# SMTPAddressFailedException: 550-Verification failed

Tags: java, email, smtp

i am using following code for sending emails using java

```
 function send(){
   String host1 = "domainname";
   String to = "test@domain.com";
   String from="dontreply@domain.com";
   String subject = "test mail";
   String messageText = "test content";
   boolean sessionDebug = false;
   Properties props = System.getProperties();
   props.put("mail.host", host1);
   props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
   Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);



       mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
           Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
   InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
   msg.setSubject(subject);
   //msg.setSentDate(new Date());
   msg.setContent(messageText,"text/html");
   Transport.send(msg);
   }
   private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator implements java.io.Serializable {
    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator() {
         String username = "support@domain.com";

        String password = "**********";
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

which works fine .But now i need to change the from address "someother@domain.com" and i have to send mails using the same authentication details as before.
if i just change my from address with the same authentication am getting the following error:

```
exceptionjavax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550-Verification failed for <someother@domain.com>
550-No Such User Here"
550 Sender verify failed
```

is this possible to send mails with same authentication and different from address.....

Can any one help me in finding the issue .....

Comment: Is the email `support@domain.com` belongs to the same domain as that of the mail server (`domainname`) ?

Comment: @Santhosh Ya having  **support@domain.com** in same domain...But i dont have this mailid **someother@domain.com** i just want my from address to be shown as **someother@domain.com**

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that there is some configuration or policy which prevents the outgoing mails where the `from` address is not registered with it. If you problem is to configure an address where the users can reply to (and which should be different from the one you are authenticating), then there is a `reply-to` header which you can set.